# datetime implementation in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

how can i get only the time from the datetime variable?
i am storing the datetime in the database. If i only need to fetch the time, how can I do it?

I have to run a single query in which I want to fetch the date and time from the datetime column. i need to use the date and time in different fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select TIME(fieldname) from tablename
```

or use the date_format() function:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 2):

Since Scott gave a SQL-based solution, there's a dead-simple way to get the time as a string in php from a MySQL datetime-formatted field.

```
$str = '2010-08-06 16:42:21';
list($date, $time) = explode(' ',$str);
echo $time;
```

Since the formatting for MySQL's datetime field follows php's `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`, a simple `explode()` on space provides two separate pieces.. one of the date, and one of the time.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution will be to use mysql function for this, so it will be faster.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('your_date_column', '%H:%i:%s') AS time FROM table;
```